# css universal selectors for all custom columns

Tags: html, css

I want to define style for different columns on my webpage as bootstrap has like `col-md-3` or `col-md-6` etc.

I want to define only few, such as only `col-md-3` and setting the width to 33%.

I used these selectors for all such columns and setting their width, which doesn't work:

```
.col-*{
    width: 33%;
}
```

or

```
*.col-{
    width: 33%;
}
```

***My question:*** How can I select all `.col` which start with `.col-` and setting their width.

Comment: Why not use `.col-xs-4` instead? Or create a separate class `.col-percent-33` - that does not overwrite Bootstrap's stylesheet?

Comment: @NisargShah not using bootstrap, its just overwriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [attribute^=value] selector matches every element whose attribute value begins with a specified value.

```
[class^="col-"]{
    width: 33%;
}
```

Note:use `!important` for overlapping, like this:`width:33%!important;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It will take some time to accept it.